# Invalid Allocation Size (in derived class copy constructor)

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-management

I have narrowed down my issue to a derived classes copy constructor, but I am unsure of the cause.
**EDIT:** M, N and Data are Private. The error I recieve is 'Invalid allocation size: 4294967295 bytes' - which I understand is caused when passing a -1 to new. I'm unsure why this would occur unless the data is lost when the class comunicate.

```
BinaryMatrix::BinaryMatrix(const BinaryMatrix& copy) : Matrix(copy)
{
    //cout << "Copy Constructor\n";

    M = copy.M;
    N = copy.N;

    data = new double[M*N]; //This line causes the allocation error

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                    data[i*N+j] = copy.data[i*N+j];
            }
    }
}
```

The above is my derived copy constructor which causes the error. I have marked the allocation line.

I can only assume that M and N are not being read correctly. Though I am unsure why. I'll include both derived and base constructors, and the base copy as well.

Thanks for any assistance.

**MATRIX (BASE) CONSTRUCTOR**

```
Matrix::Matrix(int M, int N, double* input_data)
{
    this->M = M;
    this->N = N;

    //cout << "Matrix Constructor\n";
    data = new double[M*N];

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                    data[i*N+j] = input_data[i*N+j];
            }
    }

    delete [] input_data;
}
```

**MATRIX (BASE) COPY CONSTRUCTOR**

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& copy)
{
    //cout << "Copy Constructor\n";

    M = copy.M;
    N = copy.N;

    data = new double[M*N];

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            data[i*N+j] = copy.data[i*N+j];
        }
    }
}
```

**BINARYMATRIX (DERIVED) CONSTRUCTOR**

```
BinaryMatrix::BinaryMatrix(int M, int N, double* input_data) : Matrix(M, N, input_data)
{
    data = new double[M*N];

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            this->data[i*N+j] = this->getRead(i, j);
        }
    }

    double thr_val = this->Mean();

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (this->data[i*N+j] > thr_val)
                this->data[i*N+j] = 1;

            if (this->data[i*N+j] < thr_val)
                this->data[i*N+j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doh - sorry I'll edit that into the main question now.

Comment: Is this a runtime error or compile time error?

Comment: Where are you `delete`-ing `data`? A double delete could easily confuse the memory allocator.

Comment: data is deleted in the destructor for base and derived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `M` and `N` are private to `Matrix` and `BinaryMatrix` derives from `Matrix`, I am not sure why your code compiles (you should not be able to access M, N in `BinaryMatrix`).   If your declaration of `BinaryMatrix` also includes members `M` and `N` (as well as `Matrix::N` and `Matrix::M`) then this could be the source of the problem.

If `BinaryMatrix` does not declare `M` and `N`, then I think we still don't have enough data to diagnose your problem.   To guess a bit, perhaps M*N does not fit into the type used for M.   So you have an arithmetic overflow.   The array size is specified in `size_t`, so a cast will work OK.

Also, you probably want to delegate the management of the data to exactly one of the classes.   That is, do either this:

```
BinaryMatrix::BinaryMatrix(const BinaryMatrix& copy) : Matrix(copy)
{
    // M, N, data already set in Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix&)
    // The data has also been copied, so there is nothing to do here.
}
```

or this:

```
#include <algorithm>

BinaryMatrix::BinaryMatrix(const BinaryMatrix& copy) 
 : Matrix(), M(0), N(0), 
   data(0) // null in case new throws an exception (avoid bad delete in dtor).
{
    const size_t nelems(size_t(copy.M)*size_t(copy.N));
    data = new double[nelems];
    M = copy.M;
    N = copy.N;
    stl::copy(copy.data, copy.data+nelems, data);
}
```

I think generally it is not a good idea to use `int` for iterating over dynamic data structures, since nothing guarantees that the actual size of the structure fits into `int`.  That guarantee does exist however for `size_t` (any existing object must have a size representable in `size_t`, so you can iterate over any contiguous object using `size_t`).

In fact, I'm not really sure what distinction (of purpose or behaviour) you're trying to get from `Matrix` and `BinaryMatrix`.   The data seems to have the same representation.   If it is a difference of behaviour but not representation you are looking for, I think it might be better to use composition (that is, a separate un-inherited representation class) rather than inheritance.  See [What is the Liskov Substitution Principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle) for an explanation of how to think usefully about when to use inheritance.

However, if none of the answers you have seen so far actually helps to solve your problem, you should put some time into cutting down your example: what is the smallest complete example program which demonstrates your problem?   Post that.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for your assistance. This has given me a greater understanding of Inheritance and Allocation. :)

Comment: Thank you for the further extension to your answer. Personally I don't see the point of inheritance in this case. It's one of those Uni assignments set out to teach you something in the most abstract way possible. The classes behave very differently. Binary allows only 1's and 0's, but still uses a double to hold this data. Very inneffecient. I also must incorparate greyscale, which normalises the data between 0 and 255. Your answer provided enough insight to solve the problem however. There was no need to redefine what Matrix (base) already does.

Comment: Instead I can simply use the derived methods to perform the normalisation/conversion to binary. Which is possible by following rerun's suggestion to use the Protected type.

Comment: Thanks.   I updated my answer, and hope it's more useful for you now.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you create a new copy of the matrix data in the `BinaryMatrix` copy constructor? The copy constructor of `Matrix` you call from the `BinaryMatrix` copy constructor already does this.

In the `BinaryMatrix` copy constructor you discard the copy of the matrix data the `Matrix` copy constructor already made (without `delete`ing it) and create a new one. This is a memory leak - the memory will be exhausted if you do that often enough.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is that M and N are private.  then you must change there protection level to protected or public or provide an access method that is.  Vairables defined in a base class that are private are innacceassable to the derived classes.

```
class A
{
    int x;
}

class B : public A
{
    int DoSomething()
    { 
        return x; //This is an error X is private to class A and as such inaccessible. 
    }

}
```